# How to include URL parameters in MailChimp confirmation page url

Tags: mailchimp

I'm creating a mailchimp signup form, following [this documentation.](https://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/design-and-host-your-own-thank-you-pages) I'm hosting my own signup form, so I'm specifying that URL here:

[image]

I want to include a dynamic URL parameter that will send the email address entered in the form to my thank you page.

I've tried the format [shown here](https://kb.mc4wp.com/add-variables-to-redirect-url/), and I've also tried using merge codes, like this:

```
http://example.com/thankyou?email=*|EMAIL|*
```

Or if there's an entirely different way to go about this, using a custom form or the API.

Answer (score 0):

I've chated with the Mailchimp support about this topic and the answer I've received:

> That wouldn't be possible as the merge tags only populate those values
>   in Mailchimp campaigns and hosted pages. The confirmation thank you
>   page is redirected from the signup form, the form doesn't have a way
>   to capture the email address for the purpose of that merge tag.

So an option would be to use the advanced mode in the list designer and inject the form with a refresh meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://www.example.com?email=*|EMAIL|*">
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question but just in case someone else is looking for a solution, I thought I'd share.

I just did something similar to what you're trying to do. For my use-case, I was trying to add to the URL so that I could display unique confirmation page results. So, I appended a URL parameter to the end of the Mailchimp URL in the form action. Then in the confirmation page, I'm using this script to read that URL parameter and add it to the redirect. So far, it works like a charm.

Here's my code:

```
    <script>
        var formSubmit = getUrlParameter('formSubmit');

        function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
            var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
                sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
                sParameterName,
                i;

            for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
                sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

                if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
                    return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
                }
            }

        };
        
        var link = document.createElement('meta');
        link.setAttribute('http-equiv', 'refresh');
        link.content = '0;URL=https://puredesire.org/thank-you?formSubmit=' + formSubmit;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
        
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid creating all the formulars in the advanced mode, i added the redirect statement in the body of the mailchimp confirmation page, using the text editor in html view. And it works as well.